# Stackoverflow exception in System.Core.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can someone help me to debug this issue:

I am working on an MVC webapp. I have a dynamic routing system that stores the routes in the database as `friendlyUrls`. All my friendly url logic has been working fine for months now, so it may have nothing to do with the error.

This morning I suddenly started getting `Stackoverflow` Exceptions in the `System.Core.dll` library when I navigate to a specific url namely `~/Login`. This mvc route points to a controller action (`AccountController.Login()`). The action is attributed by a custom actionfilter, but neither the action filter nor the action's code is ever hit.

The last code that I can stop using a break point is the `global.asax`'s `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` method. This method runs fine and sets the user's roles (which at that point is none because he hasn't logged in yet). Then it steps out of this method and immediately afterwards throws the `Stackoverflow` exception.

I can't find any other affected pages, but can't test it proparly, because I can't get logged into the admin pages (where the issue may also exist).

Can anyone tell me how to get more information about what is causing this issue?

Comment: Can you get the stack trace?

Comment: In order to answer this question effectively, we need the Stack trace; it's highly unlikely there's a bug in System.Core.dll, so more than likely, it's your code.  We can't tell you what the problem is unless you can include the Stack Trace and either 1) a small program that reproduces this issue or 2) the code the Stack trace brings up.

Comment: That was one of the problems in debugging it, the visual studio debugging environment doesn't have the stack trace since the stack has overflowed (overflew?) :)   - But I just figured out what the issue was: my own stupidity. I use dependency injection to inject a service which itself was calling for the original service, so it went into an infinite loop of resolving the same two dependencies! It would have been nice if Unity could recognize an issue like that and give a bit more details though. This was 4 hours I'll never get back.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I use dependency injection to inject a service which itself was calling for the original service, so it went into an infinite loop of resolving the same two dependencies! It would have been nice if Unity could recognize an issue like that and give a bit more details though.

Answer (score -1):

in my case I checked Enable Just my Code in options>debugging and it worked